# How to properly resize app to visible bounds on UWP? (VisibleBoundsMode doesn't seem to work)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have two UWP apps and after testing them out with Continuum I noticed the app bar of the OS (the bar with the Start button) at the bottom of the screen (it can be at each of the 4 edges of the screen, of course) was covering part of my app.

Now, I'm already using `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible)` before calling `Window.Current.Activate()`, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

> **1) Why is it that setting the `DesiredBoundsMode` property doesn't seem to work here?** Shouldn't that automatically resize the window
>   content to the visible bounds (ie. excluding system overlays like the
>   navigation bar or the app bar)?

---

The workaround I'm using for now on Windows 10 Mobile devices is to subscribe to the `VisibleBoundsChanged` event and then manually adjust the margins of my `Window.Current.Content` item to make sure it doesn't show anything behind covered areas of the screen.

Basically, I use the `Window.Current.Bounds` property and the `ApplicationView.VisibleBounds` property to calculate the occluded areas on the different edges of the app window, and increase the margins from there.

> **2) Is there a proper/better way to do this?**
>   I mean, I'm quite sure there's another method that should be used to avoid this issue (considering there are tons of different situations like Continuum, navigation bar etc... that I don't think are supposed to be manually handled one by one).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the subscription to the event VisibleBoundsChanged. This is the best solution that I found.

```
        var curr = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        if (curr.IsFullScreenMode == true)
        {
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
            curr.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
            curr.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Standard;
        }
```